Can't read TextBox text from a managed thread C++/CLI
I'm implementing an echo server modified from an example in the Microsoft documentation. It's implemented as a class defined in the main form header file, MainForm.h of a Microsoft Forms app. It is executed on its own thread, initiated via a button click. As a straight forward echo server it works fine.
So I decided to modify it to return a different message contained in a TextBox control when a CheckBox is not checked.
It reads the state of the CheckBox without problem, as evidenced by the debug output correctly informing me which path has been taken, but when trying to read the substitute message from the TextBox, it locks up completely.
// Loop to receive all the data sent by the client.
while ((i=stream->Read(bytes, 0, bytes->Length)) && (running)) {

    // Translate data bytes to a ASCII String*.
    message = System::Text::Encoding::ASCII->GetString(bytes, 0, i);
    
    // Update form label via delegate - works ok
    theForm->lblServerSocketMessageValueUpdate(message);
    
    // Read of CheckBox control state - works ok
    if (theForm->cbServerSocketEcho->Checked)                 
        Debug::Debug::WriteLine("Check Box is Checked");
    else {
        Debug::Debug::WriteLine("Check Box is Not Checked");
        // Read of TextBox text causes a lock up!!
        message = theForm->tbSubstituteReplyValue->Text;    
        Debug::Debug::WriteLine("Survived!");
    }
    
    cli::array<Byte>^ msg = System::Text::Encoding::ASCII->GetBytes(message);
    
    // Send back a response.
    stream->Write(msg, 0, msg->Length);
}

Why should the CheckBox be readable, but not the TextBox?

https://learn.microsoft.com/ro-ro/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-make-thread-safe-calls-to-windows-forms-controls?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Thanks for taking the time. I got there in the end using the Invoke() method. Things have moved on a bit since I last had to involve myself in C++/Windows - back in 2001.
